# BullsEye code coverage

Tags: c, arm, code-coverage

Can anyone please tell me how to perform code coverage analysis on an arm processor?

I can do the code coverage analysis by writing test cases and running them on my computer, but is it possible, without installing the code coverage tool on the target device (arm processor), to perform the coverage analysis while the codes are running on the arm processor itself?

This will save a lot time as then I won't be writing the test-cases explicitly for all the functions and the conditions involved within the embedded C code.

Comment: So  you question has nothing specifically to do with "bull eye".

Comment: ... how do you expect to avoid writing test cases for "all the functions and conditions" in the embedded program?  *Where* you test the program won't change what you have to test.

Comment: No it does have to do with BullsEye, as it is the code coverage tool that I am using for off-target test environment. And if I can integrate it during the on-target testing I will be able to test the coverage during real time without writing the test cases, which I do to emulate the real time scenarios .

Comment: @GauravMishra - You plan to test without writing test cases?  How will that work?  Anyways, a link to the documentation for that product would help people answer the question better.  Ira, the person who upvoted Ira's comments, and myself all haven't heard of this product.  I did some searching, and only found a couple of reviews from 2002 and 2007 extoling their customer support staff, and the product itself appears to be a proprietary, locked-down binary.  Ira is an expert in this subject, but as a result of this lack of information won't be able to help you much.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: It sounds like Gaurav intends to let the application execute in its embedded world to get "test" coverage.  Technically, that gets him *some* code coverage, for whatever code gets exercised. This is a place the distinction between "code coverage" (what got executed) and "test coverage" (what code got executed by tests) is a subtle but real and interesting distinction. Gaurav: best practices suggest that "testing" by just running the target device is not a good way to ensure you have good coverage. It can augment test but not replace it.

Comment: @GauravMishra: OK, well, if "Bulls Eye" is the tool you are using it better do something like the answer I gave or it won't be useful to you.  You can squirm and twwist, but you cannot avoid the problem of collecting test coverage data in the embedded device.  So look for evidence their product does something similar to what I outlined.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Yes, I get that. I cannot replace the off-target testing , as you pointed that out correctly. In fact, I should not!

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes that is the problem. Colecting the log on the computer using MS_Visual_Studio is simple but when the on-target coverage comes in place, it seems tough. Moreover, I am skeptical if it can be really done on-target and so I asked about it here. You see, I will be compiling the code on x86 processor (on my computer), using an arm compiler, but would run it on an arm processor. So,  I doubt if it will raise some dependency issues or something. Also, the code would be running continuously in a loop so how the coverage file would be edited and other things make the scenario complex.

Comment: @IraBaxter On computer I simply pass the arguments, using test-cases, and test the embedded code thereby also gathering the coverage data. But, in on-target case the same embedded code would run continuously waiting for some interrupts, at times, and other environmental triggers. So, would this emulate completely the off-target testing is quite doubtful to me. In addition the coverage data may go beyond the memory capacity of the target device causing crashes. I don't know if I should give some time into it to explore some methods to perform the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have specific experience with the arm.  I do have experience (as a designer of embedded test coverage tools) of how to collect test coverage data in an embedded system.

You need the following:

- a tool which collects runtime test coverage data in a compact format, in a simple and easily located structure in your embedded system.
- Some additional *space* in your embedded system, sufficient to hold that runtime test coverage data.  In some extremely space limited embedded systems, this can be an issue.
- An export mechanism, that can copy that data from the embedded system to a development system, at convenient moments.
- An import mechanism in the tool, that can accept such exported data

With these three elements in place, you can now collect test coverage data:

1. Instrument you code based on the development system and compile it.
2. Export the object file to the embedded system.
3. Run your embedded application, executing tests by any means you see fit
4. Export the coverage data to the development system
5. Import into the test coverage tool to interpret results.

I can't speak for "bull eye", which does do some kind of instrumentation.  Our [Test Coverage tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage) cover a variety of languages (Java, C, C#, C++, many more) and have all the necessary properties (although I have trouble imagining an embedded PL/SQL application!).

Our tools store test coverage data as a dense block of tightly packed boolean byte/bit vectors (your choice for C and C++, byte vectors for other languages).   This minimizes the extra storage demand on the embedded system.  Should even this be too much, our tools will let you collect test coverage data on smaller parts of you application, and combine the results to give test coverage for the entire embedded application.  You get to make multiple tests runs as a tradeoff but you at least can do it, and scripting can help ameliorate the tedium of the steps.

We don't dictate how the test coverage vectors (TCV) are exported from the embedded system, as that would limit which systems our tools could handle.  We provide a "standard" export function that simply writes the block of vectors directly to a development system disk file; that export system is used unchanged when doing test coverage collection on the development system itself (as you have indicated you are already doing to some extent). The export function is added to, compiled/linked with the instrumented application to enable use.   Normally it is called at program exit, but you can place calls to it at any convenient point in your application, including a point which is triggered by an outside event.   The tool contains an interactive component that will read such files and construct summary reports as well as showing you interactively what code has been executed/not.

In an embedded context, you replace the export function with one of your own.  It is only about 50 lines of code, so there's not much to replace.  On most embedded systems there are available extra I/O ports (parallel output bits, serial ports, you name it); one codes a routine that sense the binary test coverage data to this output bit.  Any embedded engineer can write a bit serializer or a send-byte-to-serial-port code block with little trouble.  At this point, the test coverage data can be exported from the embedded system.
If your embedded system has a file system, then the changes to the code are trivial if not non-existent.

The last step is to *capture* this bit stream.  This requires building a custom program running on the development system that reads some available hardware input (serial ports are easily found so this is popular) and regenerates the bit image of the test coverage data in memory.  The default export function can be copied into the custom program with slight changes to move this data to a disk file.  After this step, the test coverage interactive component can read the coverage data; it doesn't really care where it comes from.

So, with some customization of the export procedure, you can use our tools in pretty much arbitrary embedded contexts.  (We had one customer use it to test microprocessors embedded in laptop batteries!).  It takes about a day of a competent embedded engineer to fiddle the embedded version of the export function, and the development system resident part, and then you can collect test coverage to your heart's content.

This technique has been implemented by our customers with embedded systems with our C, C++, C#, and Java test coverage tools.